# Initialize multiple connection pools once for all application at startup

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, connection, tomcat7

I'm trying to initialize multiple connection pools for all the application. To achieve this I've wrote helper class:

```
public final class DataBaseHandler {

  public static final class DataSources {
    public static final DataSource DB1;
    public static final DataSource DB2;
    public static final DataSource DB3;
    public static final DataSource DB4;

    static {
      try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DB1 = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/DB1");
        DB2 = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/DB2");
        DB3 = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/DB3");
        DB4 = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/DB4");
      } 
      catch (NamingException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("DataSource is not initialized");
      }
    }
  }
```

But whenewer I try to get any of these `DataSources` in the code I'm getting an exception saying that `DataSource is not initialized`.

This is the call:

```
DataSource ds = DataBaseHandler.DataSources.DB1;
```

Looks like the `static` part of the code of `DataSources` is never being executed.
Do you have any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Chances are there is something wrong with your DataSource configuration in Tomcat. Consider moving this to a ServletContextListener and injecting the DataSource's with @Resource...

Comment: The static part is executed. Proof is the exception itself, because it gets thrown in the catchblock. Did you look at your own code? :-D

Comment: Adding `System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace());` in the catch block will give you the exact line and its cause of the exception.

Comment: @BadK, you are right. I didn't notice such an obvious thing.)

Comment: Thank you @user1354678, I will try. Good idea!

Comment: @SteveC, looks like you are right, Steve. The strange thing is that whenever I try to use `dataSource` directly on jsp page - it works fine: `<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="jdbc/DB1">` but whenever I'm trying to lookup it from `InitialContext` I'm receiving an error: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/DB1] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it turned out that there was a problem with `Context`. I had to use `env` Context:

```
Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
```

Here's working class:

```
public final class DataBaseHandler {

  public static final class DataSources {
    public static final DataSource DB1;
    public static final DataSource DB2;
    public static final DataSource DB3;
    public static final DataSource DB4;

    static {
      try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DB1 = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DB1");
        DB2 = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DB2");
        DB3 = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DB3");
        DB4 = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DB4");
      } 
      catch (NamingException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError("DataSource is not initialized");
      }
    }
  }
}
```